# How to Solve UnknownHostException while deploying DU in JBoss

Tags: jboss, centos, jain-slee

I am creating ResourceAdapter using EclipSLEE.  Following is my deploy-config.xml

**Deploy-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE deploy-config PUBLIC "-//Red Hat, Inc.//DTD JAIN SLEE Deploy Config 1.1//EN"
                               "http://www.mobicents.org/slee/dtd/deploy-config_1_1.dtd">
 <deploy-config>
    <ra-entity entity-name="AFPTelnetRA" resource-adaptor-id="ResourceAdaptorID[name=AFPTelnetRA,vendor=kalsym,version=1.0]">
     <ra-link name="AFPTelnetRA" />
     </ra-entity>
</deploy-config>
```

It is successfully deployed in JBoss running on windows10.

When I try to deploy it on JBoss running on Linux (centOS) machine. It gives following error:

**Error Logs**

```
2015-12-02 17:21:35,282 ERROR [org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.SLEESubDeployer] (HDScanner) Deployment of AFPTelnetRA-DU-1.0.jar failed.
    java.net.UnknownHostException: www.mobicents.org
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
            at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
            ...
            ...
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolve after I added following line in /etc/hosts file using vi command

```
74.125.28.121 www.mobicents.org
```